# Copying values from a previous iteration of For loop in VBA

Tags: vba, for-loop

Hope this question hasn't been asked before or is too stupid.

I'm trying to do what I thought would be relatively simple VBA task,  going through a matrix and filling out a column depending on which values can be found in other columns. If specific criterias aren't met I want to copy the value from the previous row.

This is what I thought would work:

```
For i = 1 To n
   If a(3, i) = 1 Then
      a(5, i) = 1
   ElseIf a(2, i) = 9 Then
      a(5, i) = 0
   Else
      a(5, i) = a(5, i - 1)
   End If
Next i
```

However, the 1's doesn't carry over and the cell after a 1 becomes a 0 despite the 0-condition not being met. Any suggestions?

Edit:
Here's a section of it not doing what i want, in the last two rows the second condition isn't fullfilled but the fifth column is still going to 0. I would want the macro to copy the 1 from the above cell until the second condition is met.

[matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FZ4e.png)

Comment: Could you please give an example of your matrix data (before) and your desire result of your matrix data (after)?

Comment: You are telling your macro to check if row 3 and column `i` equals 1 then row 5 and column `i` equals 1. If row 2 and column `i` equals 9 then row 5 and column `i` equals 0. Else.. row 5 column `i` equals row 5, column `i - 1`. For excel and it's arrays `a(x, y)` means `x = row` and `y = column`.

Comment: I posted a snippet of the matrix in the original post, I hope you see what I mean Wizhi. And thanks Damian, I didn't know but if I'm not missing something that shouldn't affect the function of the code posted unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @erikdansle19 you are looping all the columns in your matrix, changing over and over the same "cells" so you need to change your code to loop through all your rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
For i = 1 To n
   If a(i, 3) = 1 Then 'if row i column 3
      a(i, 5) = 1
   ElseIf a(i, 2) = 9 Then 'elseif row i column 2
      a(i, 5) = 0
   Else 'else which will only trigger if none of the ones before trigger
      a(i, 5) = a(i - 1, 5)
   End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed my code around to correctly input rows and columns but it sadly doen't change the outcome, it's still not copying the values from the row above for some reason.

Comment: @erikdansle19 it will only copy the value from the row above IF column 3 <> 1 and column <> 9. If one of these are true, it will never copy the one from the row above. In your matrix all the rows have a 1 in column 3. So it will never jump to the `Else`, will stop on the first `If`. Check how the `If` works.

Comment: Not in the last two rows, which is what's baffling me, there none of the conditions are met but I still get 0:s in column 5.

Comment: @erikdansle19 you can then try debugging step to step and check which values are showing... thats the only way.